# XML not indented on remote server via Java Transformer

Tags: java, xml, xslt

We have a problem with a Java application where we use the `javax.xml.transform.Transformer` to indent the XML string.

The problem is that it works ok on a local machine, but when deployed on a remote machine the indentation is ignored. We are using the same server (Wildfly 8.2) and the same Java(1.8) locally and on server.

The method that performs the indentation:

```
public static String transToXMLString(Document doc) {
        try {
            StreamResult sw = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
            TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer;

            transformer = tf.newTransformer();

            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");

            transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), sw);

            return sw.getWriter().toString();
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

The result on local machine:

```
13:45:30,583 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

13:45:30,583 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) <workflow URI="">

13:45:30,583 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)   <output ID="" URI="#out1"/>

13:45:30,583 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)   <input ID="sessionToken" URI="#sessionToken"/>

13:45:30,583 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)   <services>

13:45:30,584 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)     <sequence>

13:45:30,584 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)       <service URI="">

13:45:30,584 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)         <input ID="" URI=""/>

13:45:30,584 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)         <input URI="" value=""/>

13:45:30,584 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)         <output ID="" URI=""/>

13:45:30,584 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)       </service>

13:45:30,584 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)     </sequence>

13:45:30,584 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)   </services>

13:45:30,584 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) </workflow>

13:45:30,584 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)
```

The result on remote server:

```
2015-12-08 13:47:36,577 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Client : close()......
2015-12-08 13:47:36,599 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><workflow URI="">
2015-12-08 13:47:36,600 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) <output ID="" URI="#out1"/>
2015-12-08 13:47:36,600 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) <input ID="sessionToken" URI="#sessionToken"/>
2015-12-08 13:47:36,602 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) <services>
2015-12-08 13:47:36,605 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) <sequence>
2015-12-08 13:47:36,605 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) <service URI="">
2015-12-08 13:47:36,606 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) <input ID="" URI=""/>
2015-12-08 13:47:36,607 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) <input URI="" value=""/>
2015-12-08 13:47:36,608 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) <output ID="" URI=""/>
2015-12-08 13:47:36,608 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) </service>
2015-12-08 13:47:36,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) </sequence>
2015-12-08 13:47:36,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) </services>
2015-12-08 13:47:36,610 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) </workflow>
2015-12-08 13:47:36,610 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)
```

I'm showing this xml in a textarea on a web page and I need indentation there, it is strange to me that it behaves different on a local machine than on remote, the CSS are the same, tje java version is the same. It looks to me that the Transformes class behaves differentyl on local than on remote server.

I have also tried writing the Transformer output to file to avoid differences in clonsole and log settings.

The file on localhost looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<workflow URI="">
  <output ID="" URI="#out1"/>
  <input ID="sessionToken" URI="#sessionToken"/>
  <services>
    <sequence>
      <service URI="">
        <input ID="" URI=""/>
        <input URI="" value=""/>
        <output ID="" URI=""/>
      </service>
    </sequence>
  </services>
</workflow>
```

And on remote server looks (so withouth indentation):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><workflow URI="">
<output ID="" URI="#out1"/>
<input ID="sessionToken" URI="#sessionToken"/>
<services>
<sequence>
<service URI="">
<input ID="" URI=""/>
<input URI="" value=""/>
<output ID="" URI=""/>
</service>
</sequence>
</services>
</workflow>
```

So to me it looks like a different behaviour of Transformer method ... but how can it be??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have choosed DOM4J to format the xml, it is working the same both localy and remote. Here is my sniplet:

```
public static String prettyPrintXml(String xml) {

        final StringWriter sw;

        try {
            final OutputFormat format = OutputFormat.createPrettyPrint();
            format.setSuppressDeclaration(true);
            final org.dom4j.Document document = DocumentHelper.parseText(xml);
            sw = new StringWriter();
            final XMLWriter writer = new XMLWriter(sw, format);
            writer.write(document);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error pretty printing xml:\n" + xml, e);
        }
        return sw.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with XSLT but with the configuration of your logger.  The remote machine is trimming each line; the local machine is not.  Either adjust the configuration file of the server to match that of the local machine, or write the results of `transToXMLString()` directly to a file instead of via a logger.

Comment: As I commented to the previous answer I need the indentation becouse I have to show this xml in a textarea in a web page, the output to syslog was just a try to see if the output has indents, I will try aslo your duggestion and write the output to a file, but the main probem is that on the web page in a textarea the indentatoin is not present.

Answer (score 0):

For XML it is not necessary to have indents. It can contains only one string with all data. So it is OK. It can be some environment settings that not allows indents in terminal

Comment: hmm actualy I'm displaying this xml then also in a textarea on a web page and also there is withowt indent